# Unable to validate multiple select box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a multiple select box in which a user should select at least 2 values.
I use jQuery with Bootstrap. But I am not getting any result.

My html form contains a multiple select box. The form is designed using Twitter-Bootstrap. I have written a jQuery function to validate the form. I am able to validate every other input fields successfully.

Any help.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b9yoakyx/617/)

**HTML**

```
<form>       
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">multiple:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
             <select data-placeholder="Add Invitees" name="invitees[]" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="white">White</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        invitees: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What result are you expecting, what are you getting instead? pin point the issue :)

Comment: I want to select multiple values from the select box (like black, blue, green) & condition is minimum 2 items should be selected. I am not getting that. That is the issue. @sabithpocker

Comment: [You'll need to enclose any field name that contains special characters, brackets or dots, with quotation marks](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `'invitees[]'` instead of  `invitees` see the updated code.. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alenjoy333/4krxubhk/)

```
 $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            'invitees[]': {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
```